# Update GDB version on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gdb, mingw-w64

I have GDB 8.1 running on Windows 10. It came with the **latest MinGW-w64 installer package**. However, this version of the GDB is very buggy (you can't even issue a simple "call <function>" command without it crashing down in flames).

Is there any way to **update** the version?

I already downloaded the latest GDB version (currently 10.2) from here (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/), but I can't do much with it (since windows doesn't have a "make" command). Any help?

**TL,DR:**
[image]

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think mingw-w64 no longer provides any binary updates. Instead I suggest you use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: thanks, bro. it is not exactly what I was looking for, but it helps.

Comment: What ARE you looking for exactly? You want to compile the gdb source yourself? Then you'll probably need something like MSYS2 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `make` command if you install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), but building tools like that from source isn't always easy.

You could try to install via MSYS2's `pacman` tool.

There is also a GDB 8.2.1 included in the standalone builds of MinGW-w64 8.0.2 with GCC 11.1.0 and 10.3.0 from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: I agree with Brecht. The easiest thing to do is simply install it using MSYS2. After you installed MSYS2 simply run the command in msys2 terminal `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` and you can then choose the packages you wish to install (including gdb and gdb-multiarch) which are are the most up to date. You can see more instructions here: https://www.msys2.org/